# Are Decimals and Fractions Singular or Plural?

Tags: grammatical-number, fractions

I would speak 0.25 mile as twenty-five one-hundredths of a mile. Why should I write it as 0.25 miles and not 0.25 mile if it's the hundredths that are plural are singular and miles is singular?

Comment: Why do you think that 'miles' is singular?

Comment: Because if in the context of 0.25 miles "miles" wouldn't refer to a single mile then the meaning would change a little bit.

Comment: Note that the overall expression is always treated as if it were a single entity. '[0.85 miles / 1 mile / 6 miles // zero miles // half a mile ...] **_is_** what we have enough petrol left for.' ////  Using the singular- or plural-form of the base unit is up to a point a matter of style choice. This is clearly seen in 'The plank is 6 ft/foot/feet long.'